# keyUsage Extensions on a Certificate Authority

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, x.509

I have a question about what key usage should I choose when creating a private CA (root or subordinate).

I have inspected some root and issuing web certificate authorities and they tend to use `digitalSignature`, `cRLSign` and `keyCertSign`. But isn't it logical to only use  `cRLSign` and `keyCertSign` since the job of a CA is to sign other certificates and CRLs ?

Should I mark the key usage extension for a CA as critical or not? (My guess is yes, but I don't know how to justify it.)

Can someone please clarify the methodology behind these choices?

EDIT:

Example  `C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3`:

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

Comment: Interesting. Are you talking about PUBLIC CAs? If yes, then could you add the PEM certs of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## For OCSP?

I'm guessing it's for OCSP.

I've had a look at the [CAB forum Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.6.9.pdf). I did a full text search for `digitalSignature` and there are only two hits.

Hit 1/2 is for root CAs:

> b. keyUsage
> This extension MUST be present and MUST be marked critical. Bit positions for keyCertSign and cRLSign
> MUST be set. If the Root CA Private Key is used for signing OCSP responses, then the digitalSignature bit
> MUST be set.

Hit 2/2 is for subordinate CAs:

> e. keyUsage
> This extension MUST be present and MUST be marked critical. Bit positions for keyCertSign and cRLSign
> MUST be set. If the Subordinate CA Private Key is used for signing OCSP responses, then the digitalSignature
> bit MUST be set.

Comment: Boom! That's probably exactly it!

Comment: @MikeOunsworth: I'm guessing so, yes. But it's only a regular *"if"* and not an *"if and only if"*, so I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're right. [RFC 5280 section 4.2.1.3. Key Usage](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3) says (emphasis mine):

> ```
> KeyUsage ::= BIT STRING {
> ```

```
       digitalSignature        (0),
       nonRepudiation          (1), -- recent editions of X.509 have
                            -- renamed this bit to contentCommitment
       keyEncipherment         (2),
       dataEncipherment        (3),
       keyAgreement            (4),
       keyCertSign             (5),
       cRLSign                 (6),
       encipherOnly            (7),
       decipherOnly            (8) }
```

> Bits in the KeyUsage type are used as follows:

> The digitalSignature bit is asserted when the subject public key
> is used for verifying digital signatures, ***other than signatures on
> certificates (bit 5) and CRLs (bit 6)***, such as those used in an
> entity authentication service, a data origin authentication
> service, and/or an integrity service.

> ...

> However, the digitalSignature
> and/or nonRepudiation bits MAY be set in addition to the keyCertSign
> and/or cRLSign bits if the subject public key is to be used to verify
> signatures on certificates and/or CRLs as well as other objects.

My guess is that CAs want the ability to use the root key for some other kind of authentication; who knows, maybe signing logs or something? Either that or it's misconfiguration.

---

Full disclosure, I work for Entrust, so I'll use them as an example: the publicly-trusted [Entrust Root Certificate Authority—G2](https://www.entrustdatacard.com/pages/root-certificates-download) and the L1K and L1M issuing CAs do not have the `digitalSignature` keyUsage, so it's certainly not needed:

[image: Entrust Root Certificate Authority—G2 does not have the digitalSignature key usage]

---

As for your other question:

> Should I mark the key usage extension for a CA as crticial or not ? (my guess is yes, but I don't know how to justify it)

RFC 5280 (same section) says:

> When present, conforming CAs SHOULD mark this extension as critical.

I'm not sure what happens if you mark this as non-critical, but I'm guessing some clients / verifiers will work fine, and some will have weird behaviours.